# Bounded sequence of polynomials

Tags: general-topology, polynomials

Let $N$ a norm on $\mathbb{R}_N[X ]$ , $P_n$ a bounded sequence of monic polynomial of $\mathbb{R}_N[X ]$.
Suppose that $Q_n$ a sequence of monic polynomials such that $Q_n$ divide $P_n$ for all $n$ . Prove that $Q_n$ is bounded.
Since we are in finite dimension , it suffices to find a nice norm for which we have $N_1(Q_n) \leq c.N_1(P_n)$ . I tried max , sum of coefficients but it doesn't work . Any ideas ?

Comment: what is $\mathbb R_{\mathbb N}$?

Comment: max (of absolute values) of coefficients is enough

Comment: you don't need $N(Q_n)\le c N(P_n)$, but something a lot weaker. For example, $N(Q_n)\le c N(P_n)^b$ is also enough

Comment: You should have `\mathbb{R}_N[X]` not `\mathbb{R_N[X]}` --- the N and X shouldn't be blackboard bold.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prove the following:

> A set of monic polynomials of  bounded degree,  is bounded in norm if and only if the absolute values of the roots are also bounded.

On one side, you can find a bound on the roots by Gerschgorin circles on the companion matrix, or with classical Cauchy bounds.

On the other side, use the Viète formula to find a bound on coefficients given the roots.

Comment: I got it , thanks a lot for you hint !